# find coordinate of object in a image after using grabcut (python)

Tags: python, image-processing, crop

I have lots of lobster images (with the same background).

My goal is to measure the size of each lobster.

To do this, I use Grabcut to extract the main object (lobster) from the background. However, after this step, I don't know how to find the coordinates of extracted object for cropping purpose. I need to crop the object to support size measuring.

I don't know whether:

- we have any direct way to save only the extracted object to a new image (just fit the size of the object), or
- find its coordinates after doing Grabcut.

If we don't have either of the above I'd  appreciate it if you tell me about other methods to do object cropping from Grabcut output.

This is original image
[image: This is original image]

This is the output image after Grabcut
[image: This is the output image after Grabcut.]

The output image is still the same size as the original image.

I need to save the extracted object to a new image that fits enough the object's size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some thing called as [min Bounding Rectangle](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) from OpenCV Library. It forms a smallest rectangle and gives the coordinates of the rectangle.

Bounding Rect : It gives the un-rotated rectangle (green rectangle)

```
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
```

Rotated Bounding Rect : It gives the rotated bounding rectangle (red rectangle)

```
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(img,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
```

[Image from OpenCV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVQwm.png)

After this you can take the coordinates and extract the rectangle with the lobster.

Comment: Thanks user3808268 for quick reply. I have used your solution with the following code for the Grabcut output image above: import cv2 import numpy as np img = cv2.imread('output.jpg',0) print (img.shape) ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0) ,contours, = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2) im2,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2) cnt = contours[1500] x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt) print(x, y, w, h) cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2) crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w] cv2.imshow("Crop", crop_img) cv2.waitKey(0)

Comment: When I run the code above, I can't get the desired result. 
The first issue is that it doesn't display the green rectangle. I don't know the why. 
The second issue is that, when I take the values of x,y,w,h for cropping, it shows completely wrong area and it's very tiny. The reason is the values of w and h are very small and I also don't know why. 
I also realised that, the 'contours' output from cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2) contains a very large number of values. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, you need to binarize (black and white) the output of grab-cut -> then apply [dilation and erosion](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/) (this will remove the small x,y,w,h) -> then apply contour -> then use these x,y,w,h values to extract the lobster.       
           For displaying the rectangle, you have to do : img_with_rect = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)  Then do cv2.imshow("Image with Rect", img_with_rect).

Comment: First do erosion, then dilation, it will remove the disturbing points and fix the small x-y-w-h problem (it's input is a binarzied image (black and white))    eroded_img =  cv2.erode(black_white_img, None, iterations=5)  dilated_img =    cv2.dilate(eroded_img, None, iterations=3)

Comment: That's great. Your solution works perfectly. Thanks for your instruction.